# mysql.connector, plotly.express exception

Tags: python

This is my first question I post here.
I'm trying to create a program that will get data from database and create graphs from them. I'm getting this exception every time I run this code. If I use only the mysql part or the plotly part it works, but if together it doesn't. Any suggestions how to fix it?

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="test1",
    password="test2",
    database="testdatabase"
)

fig = px.line(x=['a', 'b'], y=[1, 2])
```

Getting this exception:

Exception ignored in: <function BaseMySQLSocket.**del** at 0x0CFE3928>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Acer Nitro 5\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 149, in **del**
File "C:\Users\Acer Nitro 5\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 137, in shutdown
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed